# How to store more than String's limit in a variable in Groovy?

Tags: java, string, groovy, inputstream, inputstreamreader

In process of converting a variable of **Data Type InputStreamReader (stdout)** into **String (s)** I am reading few characters of 'stdout' at a time through 'ca' and appending it to 's'. However since the data to be read is too long, I think after some time the storing variable reaches its limit and stops appending data onto it. So the truncated result is being shown on the CLI.

It's essential for the whole output to be stored together so as to parse it afterwards in the remaining code. Below is the code snippet

```
def lastRead = System.currentTimeMillis()
def s = ''
def lastStdout = 0
def ca = new char[4096]

while (true)
{
    int len

    while (stdout.ready() && (len = stdout.read(ca)) > 0)
    {
        //trace.severe(CliConnection.class, s)
        s = s + new String(ca, 0, len)
        //trace.severe(CliConnection.class, ca)
        lastRead = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
     s = config.stdoutFilters.inject(s.normalize()) { t, filter -> filter(t) }
    //trace.info(CliConnection.class, "In loop: >>${s}<<")

    if (options.stdout && s.length() > lastStdout) {
        //trace.info(CliConnection.class, s)
        options.stdout(s.substring(lastStdout))
        lastStdout = s.length()
    }
    if (stop(s, lastRead))
        break
                // wait for certain period to get the date correctly
                // default is 100 if it is set under 100
                def iodelay = (getIOdelay() > 100) ? getIOdelay() : 100
    Thread.sleep(iodelay)
}
```

In the given code, the variable ca keeps on reading further data but it doesn't append on to the variable s. So it throws no error, just truncates the output data. 
Is there a way to overcome the problem or some other method that can be tried instead?

Comment: try writing in the same loop as you are reading from. Now you are reading everything before writing it to stdout.

Comment: If there's no exception, then problem somewhere else. In output for example.

Comment: @daggett You were right. The problem was in the output getting truncated. The variable was storing everything, just not displaying it.